# Comparing 2 String not giving desired output

Tags: apex

```
String enterNewPass = 'Simple@123';
String enterReNewPass = 'simple@123';

System.debug(enterNewPass == enterReNewPass);
```

Why Apex code not giving false result when comparing above 2 string, Is Apex comparing case safe  or not, How to compare such strings?

The above code returns True but I need a result False because it didn't check case-sensitive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use string [equals](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_string.htm#apex_System_String_equals_2) method for case sensitive string comparison.

```
String enterNewPass = 'Simple@123';
String enterReNewPass = 'simple@123';

System.debug(enterNewPass.equals(enterReNewPass));//returns false
```